# Not allowed to load local resources in apache webserver

Tags: php, html, apache, raspberry-pi

I have an Apache web server in a Raspberry Pi where I need to display a couple of graphs that use the MPLD3 libraries; these are being loaded from the server's folder. I'm getting `Not allowed to load local resources` on the console when I run my index.php page, however, I've copied the code inside that file, pasted it inside a test file, opened it just with the browser (not, through the server), and it worked just fine. This is the error I've encountered:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file://` protocol references the local machine, that the browser is running on. If you are referencing a file with that protocol on the Raspberry Pi, you are actually trying to open a file on the local machine - not the Raspberry. Since this is a security issue, it is not allowed.

You should move all required files to the Raspberry Pi, and reference them using the HTTP protocol.

Comment: The files are all in the RPi, I'm doing all of this with it, too. I'm trying to get this to work using the localhost.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that you cannot combine the two protocols. If you open a page with HTTP, you cannot reference the file protocol. You will have to reference the JavaScript files via the HTTP protocols also.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. First, sorry if this is very elementary, I'm not a programmer by trade. So, I can use the HTTP protocol to reference the JS files even though they will be in a directory in the RPi and not online?

Comment: That is correct. For simplicity, you should be able to place your JavaScript files next to the `index.php` file and reference them only by doing `//d3.js`

Comment: By the way - when you consider this question answered, please mark it as answered with the check mark :-)

Comment: Just tried this last solution, and it didn't work, unfortunately. I got a new error: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. However, the filename is correct.

Comment: This means that the domain name, that you are requesting the JavaScript files trough, is not an existent one. This should probably be the same domain/IP as used to access the `index.php` file.